# Firebug's jQuery won't load on my site

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, firebug

Jquery works fine. Everything is functional. If I open up console and type :

```
console.log($)
```

it returns :

```
 function()
```

But if I type:

```
$("p")
```

I get:

```
null
```

Literally for anything. Strange! So I open up Google Chrome and try out their Console. Chrome returns :

```
undefined
```

jQuery is properly embedded in the header. And again, everything is working fine on the site itself.

**Side Note**

I just upgraded Firefox, and realizing that it was too early for my plugins to catch up, I uninstalled it and installed 7. jQuery does work perfectly alright on other sites.

Comment: I have noticed Firebug losing scope at times, producing the same issue. What happens if you use `window.jQuery` or `window.$`?  Problem is, I have never seen such an issue in Chrome, so this is quite possibly something wrong on your end.

Comment: Are you sure you have anything on your page?

Comment: @JAAulde: only `window.jQuery` returns the proper output.

Comment: @Blender yeah, I went to the site and started poking around. It's quite odd in that `$` in the console outputs `function()` but it doesn't point to any source. Also, `$.toSource()` causes an error for undefined. However, `jQuery` works fine. It's almost as if something has put jQuery into no conflict mode, though it looks a little different.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When I tried going to your site `$` is `undefined`

---

I just noticed in one of your files you have: `var $j = jQuery.noConflict();`

This makes `$` undefined and sets `$j` as your jQuery handler. ([see source here](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=git&fn=jQuery.noConflict))

So if you try `$j('selector')` it works fine ^_^

(the name of the file is `bwbps.js`)

Comment: Genius! Gar wordpress pre-packaged mumbo jumbo got me again. Super THANKS!

Comment: @Sonny he can't yet ^_^ there is a 15 minute rule

Comment: Ah, so it is in no conflict mode. I noticed the $j and the $jw, but didn't track downt heir definitions. +1 @Neal

Comment: Only 20 seconds left before this is getting a wopping green mark.

Answer (score 1):

try `console.log(jQuery)` or

```
$ = jQuery;
console.log($);
```